# How to find if cell value is 0%?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to compare percentage in cells.

```vb
dim ws as worksheet
dim LastRow as long

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "test1" And ws.Name <> "test2" Then
        LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        For i = 3 To LastRow
            If ws.Range("M" & i).Value = 0 Then  '<---here it give me error
                ws.Range("M" & i).Locked = True
            End If
        Next i

    End If
Next ws
```

In Column M in my sheet, the whole column starting from M3 is percentage format type.

I want to find out if the cell is 0%.

Let's say range("M5") is 0%, I want to check format protection to lock the cells and last protect the worksheet.

I have tried many code such as:

```
    ws.Range("M" & i).Value = 0
    ws.Range("M" & i) = 0
    ws.Range("M" & i).Value = "0"
    ws.Range("M" & i) = "0%"
```

It gives type mismatch error.

Comment: It shouldn't matter the formatting of the cell itself. Something else is going on.

Comment: but it show the type mismatch ( run time error 13)

Comment: I'm not saying you're lying. I believe you I am just trying to figure out the root cause - the formatting of your cell shouldn't be it.

Comment: if i delete 

    "if ws.Range("M" & i).Value = 0 Then" and 

    "end if"

it works normally.

Comment: Long shot here, but can you change `.Value` to `.Value2`?

Comment: i have changed, but not working...but anyway if the programme can't work, i can do it by manually even it will cost a long time. so never mind, thanks buddy, i will check the programme again after finshing the locking process.

Comment: Do you have any error values in that column?

Comment: Nice one, @BigBen. That would certainly do it

Comment: but i check it once again, no error value in that column, the percentage column i use a formula to calculate it and change to percentage. some #N/A is here, but even when i delete all of the #N/A, it's still got me the error.

Comment: Right above the line giving you trouble, can you type `Debug.Print ws.Range("M" & i).Value`? Then Press `Ctrl+G` in the VBE and see what the last line says in the immediate window when you run your code? @Nicawong9147

Comment: it only shows me 3 zero, maybe the error  stuck in the fourth zero

Comment: Sorry, i find the problem now. some 0% in cell is '0% but some of it is 0%, and i untick the background error checking. thus i cannot see the different if i don't click in the cells. Sorry buddy, and thanks for your helping.

Comment: Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some error checking on the cell first:

```
For i = 3 To LastRow
    If Not IsError(ws.Range("M" & i)) Then
        If ws.Range("M" & i).Value = 0 Then
            ws.Range("M" & i).Locked = True
        End If
    End If
Next i
```